# runtime error Illegal instruction in Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

Can anyone help me with this problem?

I need to create an asm program that will accept a user sure name, and ask the user if he is sure of the sure name he entered, then the user will choose `y/n`. If the user enters `y` the program will then print the message then you might be chris + the user surname, and if he enters `n` the program will jump back and ask for the surname again.  If he enters other than `y` or `n` the program will jump back and ask "are you sure?"

When I run the program I encountered an error. Here is my code:

```
.model small
.stack 64h
.data
    msg01 db 13, 10, "What is your surename?: ", "$"
    msg02 db 13, 10, "Are you sure? y/n", "$"
    msg03 db 13, 10, "Then you must be chris ", "$"

    nameinput label byte
    maxnamelen db 20
    curnamelen db ?
    namefield db 20 dup(?)

.code
    start:
            mov ax, @data
            mov ds, ax

    inputsurename:
            mov ax, 09h
            mov dx, offset msg01
            int 21h

            mov ah, 0ah
            mov dx, offset nameinput
            int 21h

            mov bx, 0
            mov bl, curnamelen
            mov namefield [bx], "$"


    inputchoice:

            mov ax, 09h
            mov dx, offset msg02
            int 21h

            mov ah, 1
            int 21h

            cmp al, 'n'
            je inputsurename

            cmp al, 'y'
            jne inputchoice

    printname:
            mov ah, 09h
            mov dx, offset msg03
            int 21h

            mov ah, 09h
            mov dx, offset namefield
            int 21h

            mov ah, 4ch
            int 21h

    end start
```

Comment: Your question is missing some important information. For example, what are you running this program on? DOSBox? An old computer that has DOS on it..? And what input, if any, are you providing to the program when you get the error?

Answer (score 0):

The two `mov ax, 09h` are wrong. This instruction causes `AL` to be 09h and `AH` to be 00h. But for `int 21h/09h` you need `AH`=09h. So change it to `mov ah, 09h`.

Comment: hi thank you so much. i just don't know what's the difference between the two because i thought they are the same accumulator. they're teaching us how to program using asm, but i have a little knowledge of the machine... somehow i know the hows but i don't know about the whys.

Comment: A short description about a lot of specific function calls can be found in some of the zip-containers in Ralf Browns x86/MSDOS Interrupt List (RBIL).